# Sort text in Option Button

Tags: livecode

I have an option button with some values

```
Scotland
Switzerland
England
```

I would like to sort these lines alphabetically.
How can I do that?

```
sort the text of button btn_type ascending(each)
```

or some variation of that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the word "the":

```
sort lines of btn "Your option button"
```

and you do not even need the "lines" since this is assumed unless explicitly modified, to, say, items.

```
sort btn "Your option button"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. tried so many other ways but always kept the  `the`

Answer (score 0):

First get the text of the button, then sort it, then set the text of the button:

```
put the text of btn "Your option button" into myText
sort lines of myText
set the text of btn "Your option button" to myText
```

Probably you can also do it directly:

```
sort lines of btn "Your option button"
```

The sort function is ascending by default, so you don't need to include that.

Comment: I could do the first but I was hoping for a solution like your second code. But that throws an error

`card "d": compilation error at line 201 (Chunk: missing chunk) near "lines", char 9`

Comment: I accidentally wrote `the lines`instead of `lines`. I have updated the code in the answer. Please try again.